# Call notifiyDataSetChanged() from android viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I'm making a reactive app with a lot of data using Android MVVM. There are a lot of cases where I push data to firestore documents in my app, but i also want this change in data to be reflected locally in my app. So I also add the data to the local copy (data class) of the firestore document. I do this in my viewmodel.

The problem here is that I won't see change until I restart the app. So I need a way to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from my viewmodel so the recyclerviews are updated immediately. Whats the best way to do this? Please help.

Comment: If you're using MVVM, the view-model ought to provide a way to subscribe to data changes so the Adapter can subscribe and call its own `notifyDataSetChanged` when there is a change. Since you are storing a local copy in your view-model, you could wrap it in a LiveData and let the relevant Fragment `observe` that and react.

Answer (score 0):

As you change and update data frequently, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged isn't helpful in this case because even if you update one item it will update the whole list even when the rest not touched!

So A better way to make your adapter

1-  `extend ListAdapter<data_model, view_holder>(diff_callback)`. 
this Uses AsyncListDiffer under the hood to calculate and update the changed items only

2-whenever you need to update your data in viewmodel call:

```
adapter.submitList()
```

For more information on how to do that: 
   check doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Yours ViewModel should't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` directly for two reasons:

1. Adapter is Android dependency. And if you want to [write unit tests to yours view model](https://proandroiddev.com/building-unit-tests-for-viewmodel-in-tdd-style-f8c502681ad4) you should avoid use android framework dependencies
2. I think `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is UI logic implementation detail. And will be better if we move this logic to our view layer (`fragment/activity/custom views`)

You could solve this problem by encapsulate `notifyDataSetChanged` logic in yours adapter like this:

```
// Observe live data changes and set it to yours adapter
viewModel.state().observe(this, Observer {
      newData: List<....> ->
      adapter.setData(newData)
})

// Encapsulate notifyDataSetChanged at yours adapter:
class YoursAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    fun setData(data: List<.....>) {
        ......
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

In this case it's very easy to change adapter implementation from `notifyDataSetChanged()` to more precise updates like `notifyItemInserted()` later for example.

But I'm also recommend do not use notifyDataSetChanged() function and prefer [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil). Or use libraries that can help with recycler view boilerplate and already have DiffUtil support under the hood. For example I like to use [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) in my projects